# zebra zpl printer language - how to tell printer to force cut

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

good day. is there a command to tell the printer to immediately cut the paper after printing a line of text ? even if the line of text is in the middle of the label.

I've tried ^MMT,N but that command will cut at the end of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^MMC is for cut. MMT is for tear off. 
But I am not sure if this is possible to cut just after line of text. In printer there can be a detector to find end of label (you can also try manipulate with force change length of label by manually changing its length)